# Finding Perimeter of Shape

Tags: geometry, circles

"Two circles of radii 5cm and 12cm overlap so that the distance between their centers is 13cm.
Find the perimeter of the shape."

This question was from a chapter about circle measure under the length of an arc in P1 AS Mathematics.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: I guess it's a Pythagorean triple

Comment: For future use here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting functions into mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perimeter is the sum of the perimeters of the two circles less the lengths of arcs inside. So referring to the diagram below it is $2\pi(12+5)-2CD-2CE$. The arc $CD$ has length $12\angle ABC$ (where the angle is measured in radians) and the arc $CE$ has length $5\angle BAC$.

We have $\tan ABC=\frac{AC}{BC}=\frac{5}{12}$, so $\angle ABC=\tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}$ and $\angle BAC=\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}$.

Thus the perimeter is $29\pi-14\tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}\approx85.6$

[image]

Comment: can you tell me please what is the name of the software you used to draw that? is it geogebra?

Comment: No, it is Geometer's Sketchpad. I use OS X. I am not sure if it is available on Windows. It is useful for Euclidean geometry but not for general graphics. Also it is not freeware.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. You have 2 circumferences: $x^2+y^2 = 25$ and $(x-13)^2 + y^2 = 144$. You can find the intersection between the two circumferences putting in a sistem the two equations. You find 2 points: $(1.92,4.62)$ and $(1.92,-4.62)$. Now you had to find the angle between center of both cirumferences and this point (i used a program). The angle is 225.24° for the first one, and 314.76° for the second one. Then use the formula Arch = (2*pi*r*angle)/360 for both circumferences and add the results. You obtain $27.23*\pi$